# Read individual files in spark cluster and process as one context

Tags: apache-spark

I'm beginner of `Spark` and `SparkJob Server`.

- I have to process log files which contains user_name and get the number of unique user.
- Log files stored in 5 different locations(Different server connected with LAN).
- Same user name can be repeated in different locations(Assume server 1 log can have a particular username and server 2 also can have same username) .

**Problem**

I thought I can use `Spark Cluster` but I have a confusion. If I write a query to get the unique users in spark (In cluster mode) , will it process individually in each node and get the number and send to master or Master will get all log files and read as one context and get the count ..?

Because it might give wrong count if the log files processed individually in each node.